# How do I format printing a integer so that all the places to the left of the decimal line up?

Tags: java

This program runs fine the issue is a formatting one when "System.out.print("Tax:           $%.2f\n", tax);" line runs. The issue is that I need to output to line up with the other outputs. I've tried simply using space, but then when it's any bigger than three places to the left of the decimal it no longer lines up.
[This image shows what my output is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO8Bt.png)

[This image shows what my output should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3asG.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

/**
 *Program generates pay stub for employee.
 *Details several variables.
 * @author Taylor Schaefer ts1178
 * @version 19
 */

public class PayStub {

    /**
     * @param args insert description here
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Install scanner and declare all variable
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Inputting name
        System.out.print("Enter your Fullname: ");
        String fullName = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Inputting anniversary month
        System.out.print("Enter your Anniversary Month(1-12): ");
        int month = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Inputting anniversary year
        System.out.print("Enter your Anniversary Year: ");
        int year = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Hours per week worked
        System.out.print("Enter your hours worked this pay period(0-350): ");
        int hours = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Inputting name
        System.out.print("Enter your Job Title: ");
        String blank = keyboard.nextLine();
        String jobTitle = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Hourly pay rate
        System.out.print("Enter your pay rate:");
        double rate = keyboard.nextDouble();

        //current pay month 9
        //current pay year 2018
        int day = 1;
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2018, 9, 1);
        //calculate the time that has passed
        Period age = Period.between(start, today);
        int years = age.getYears();
        int months = age.getMonths();
        //Print total number of months worked and declare variable total months
        int totalMonths = months + years * 12;

        //Declare Variable vacation Hours
        double vacation = totalMonths * 8.25;

        //Declare and define gross pay
        double grossPay = hours * rate;

        //Declare and calculate retirement
        double retirement = grossPay * .052;

        //Declare and calculate tax withholding
        double tax = (grossPay - retirement) * .28;

        //Declare and calculate net pay
        double netPay = grossPay - (tax + retirement);

        //Print Payroll
        //
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("==========================================");
        //Company Name
        System.out.println("      Gekko & Co.");
        System.out.println();
        //Print Logo
        System.out.println("          \"$\"");
        System.out.println("          ~~~");
        System.out.println("         /  \\ `.");
        System.out.println("        /    \\  /");
        System.out.println("       /_ _ _ \\/");
        System.out.println(); //divider
        //Single Line Divider
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        //Print Pay Period
        System.out.println("Pay Period:     9/2018");
        //Print Name
        System.out.println("Name:           " + fullName);
        //Print Title
        System.out.println("Title:          " + jobTitle);
        //Print anniversary month and year
        System.out.println("Anniversary:    " + month + "/" + year);
        //Print months worked
        System.out.println("Months Worked:  " + totalMonths + " months");
        //Print vacation hours earned
        System.out.printf("Vacation hours: %.2f\n", vacation);
        //Single Line Divider
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        //Print Gross Pay
        System.out.printf("Gross Pay:     $%.2f\n", grossPay);
        //Print Retirement Amount
        System.out.printf("Retirement:    $ %.2f\n", retirement);
        //Print Tax withholding amount
        System.out.printf("Tax:           $%.2f\n", tax);
        //Single Line Divider
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        //Print Net Pay
        System.out.printf("Net Pay:       $%.2f\n", netPay);
        //Print Footer
        System.out.println("==========================================");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the width specifier - which includes the decimal point and precision so for a value like 815.74 to line up with a value like 3073.18 use `$%7.2f`.

```
System.out.printf("abc $%7.2f%n", 815.74);
System.out.printf("abc $%7.2f%n", 3073.18);
```

prints

```
abc $ 815.74                                                                                                                                                                       
abc $3073.18
```

Of course if you can't assume the maximum number of digits then you'd compute the max digits - and while we're at it throw in some commas (and account for them for width) (aka comma grouping separator):

```
// here you'd compute the max value of all the numbers your printing
double maxValue   = 1721890.23;

int maxDigits     = ((int)Math.log10(maxValue) + 1);
int numCommas     = (maxDigits-1) / 3;
int precision     = 2;
int precDecimalPt = (precision + 1);
int totalWidth    = (maxDigits+precDecimalPt+numCommas);

String formatStr = "$%,"+totalWidth+"."+precision+"f%n";

System.out.printf("Gross Pay:    "+formatStr, 815.74);
System.out.printf("Retirement:   "+formatStr, 3073.18);
System.out.printf("Tax:          "+formatStr, maxValue);
```

prints:

```
Gross Pay:    $      815.74                                                                                                                                                        
Retirement:   $    3,073.18                                                                                                                                                        
Tax:          $1,721,890.23
```

Then let's say you had a bunch of prefix text of varying length and didn't want to account for spaces for padding but wanted all the text to line up and be aligned to the left...then format that too with a width specifier and a left-justified flag:

```
 // replaces portion of above...

 String formatStr = "%-30s$%,"+totalWidth+"."+precision+"f%n";

 System.out.printf(formatStr, "Gross Pay:", 815.74);
 System.out.printf(formatStr, "Retirement:", 3073.18);
 System.out.printf(formatStr, "Tax:", maxValue);
```

prints

```
Gross Pay:                    $      815.74                                                                                                                                        
Retirement:                   $    3,073.18                                                                                                                                        
Tax:                          $1,721,890.23
```

Other considerations to account for:

- can a value ever be negative and displayed as such
- what happens when prefix is larger than accounted for